Density of totalvariation of a measure
We have proven a statement for complex measures in our lecture recently, but I cannot follow one specific step of the proof:
Theorem
Let $\mu$ be a complex measure on $(X,\mathscr{A})$. Then there exists a measurable function $g: X \to \mathbb{C},\ \lvert g(x) \rvert = 1, \lvert \mu \rvert$-a.e. such that
$\forall A \in \mathscr{A}: \mu(A) = \int_A g \ d\lvert\mu\rvert $
$\lvert\mu\rvert \ldots$ total variation
Proof:
From Theorem (...) $\Rightarrow l: f \mapsto \int_X f d\lvert\mu\rvert$ is a continous and linear mapping. Theorem (...) $\Rightarrow \exists! \bar{g} \in L^2(\lvert\mu\rvert): l(f) = \int_X fg \ d\lvert\mu\rvert$. Thus, $\mu(E) = l({1}_E) = \int_E g \ d\lvert\mu\rvert \ldots$.
The proof goes on after that, yet this step is the one that troubles me where does this come from? Our definition of the totalvariation is $\lvert\mu\rvert (E) = \sup \{\sum_j \lvert\mu(A_j)\rvert \bigr| E= \biguplus_j A_j\}$.

Ok, I have found my mistake: we can/should choose
$l: f \mapsto \int_X f\ d\mu$
and then apply the theorem that for every linear functional there exists exactly $g \in L^2(\lvert\mu\rvert): l(f) = \int_X fg\ d\lvert\mu\rvert$.
